# Launching Facebook Instant Game from web

Tags: facebook, facebook-instant-games

I am looking for a way to launch Facebook Instant Games in the native mobile app from an external site. I have managed to launch the game in the desktop site simply by extracting from the built-in play button href's (e.g. https://www.facebook.com/instantgames/play/id_here). However I am having difficulty finding a way to launch the Messenger games from anywhere external.

Not sure if this is possible and far from my best Stack Overflow question, but the docs are helpless, so any help would be greatly appreciated, and also not to be crucified for the question as I don't have much more information to provide unfortunately.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As long as you have a page associated with your Instant Game you can use an m.me deeplink (e.g. m.me/everwinggame?game=everwing).

The format of these links is m.me/{page id}?game={game namespace}.

There's more information [here](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/games/instant-games/test-publish-share#deeplink), but appreciate the feedback on our documentation. Thanks!

Comment: Unfortunately the link 404's for me but this should do the trick. Thank you, much appreciated!

Comment: If the link 404s for you might not be in our beta program and therefore don't have access. Ensure you're in [this Facebook group](http://www.facebook.com/groups/instantgamedevelopers).

Comment: Does this link to the Facebook app or the Messenger app ?

Comment: @Taiko this links to the Facebook Messenger app.

Comment: Can you give me a hint how to add a parameter to the URL, which I can read later again in the instant game e.g. for tracking campaigns?